# Is it possible to check for enum.equals() usage?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We recently ran into a bug in our code where someone had used .equals() to compare enums.  One of the fields had been changed to a different enum - but we got no compiler error due to the use of .equals() instead of ==.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include language

Comment: It should be possible to implement a rule related to the use of equals() on "enum" but you need to precise the use case by sharing some sample code (reproducer of the problem) so we are clear about what you want to catch.

Answer (score 1):

Can you look at this specification and tell if this is matching the problem you want to catch? (assuming you are talking about Java)

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-4551

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for.
So, when?

Comment: Probably in the next 2-3 months, it's scheduled for SonarJava 5.5 for the moment